# Importing empty csv file in sas

Tags: sas

I'm trying to import series of CSV files files from a folder. Some of these CSV files could just have a header and no data in them. How can I exclude importing such files?

here is the code

```
filename file1 'user/reports/RPT1.csv';
filename file2 'user/reports/RPT2.csv';

proc import file=file1
dbms=dlm
out=file1 
replace;
delimiter=',';
getnames=yes;
run;

proc import file=file2
dbms=dlm
out=file2 
replace;
delimiter=',';
getnames=yes;
run;

data combined;
set file1
file2;
run;

data xlout.rpt1;
set file1;
run;

data xlout.rpt2;
set file2;
run;
```

Comment: Do you have XCMD access? If so, you can use command line approaches to check the number of rows in each data set and then process only the datafilee you want to.

Comment: Do you have to use PROC IMPORT?  Don't you know what is in the files in advance? The problem with PROC IMPORT for CSV files is that it uses the data to guess how to define the variables. If there are zero lines of data it has no information on how to define the variables.

Answer (score 3):

You can just read the CSV files to count the number of lines. If you only need to know if the file has 2 or more lines you just need to read two lines of the file.

Here is code that will set a macro variable to 0,1 or 2 based on whether the text file has none, one or two or more lines.

```
data _null_;
  if _N_ > 2 or eof then do; 
     call symputx('FLAG',_n_-1); 
     stop; 
  end;
  infile file1 end=eof;
  input;
run;
```

You can then use that macro variable to control whether to run the PROC IMPORT step

```
%if (&flag > 1) %then %do;
  proc import datafile=File1 ....
%end;
```

or later steps that use the output of the PROC IMPORT.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the actual scenario, you can turn of the `DSNFERR` option.  DSNFERR means *Data set not found, cause error*.  When the setting is off, some reasonable default continuance actions will happen instead of an error.

Example:
Create some two text files to import from.  One of them is 'empty' and has only headers.  Import from the files and perform some data processing.

```
filename f1 'c:\temp\f1.csv';
filename f2 'c:\temp\f2.csv';

proc export data=sashelp.class(obs=0) replace file=f1 dbms=csv;
run;

proc export data=sashelp.class replace file=f2 dbms=csv;
run;

proc import file=f1 dbms=csv replace out=file1; getnames=yes;
proc import file=f2 dbms=csv replace out=file2; getnames=yes;
run;

options NODSNFERR;

data stacked;
  set file1 file2;
run;

data work.rtp1;
  set set file1;
run;

data work.rtp2;
  set set file2;
run;

options DSNFERR;
```